# E: Unable to locate package ntop

Tags: package-management, lubuntu, ntop

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 and have been trying to install ntop package, But every time I enter

apt-get install ntop

get an error on terminal:-

E: Unable to locate package ntop

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ny9l.png

I tried firing the same command as a root-user, nothing works!!

Sorry, but I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Ntopng? "Ntopng is an open source tool used to monitor different network protocols on your servers. It is the next generation version of the original Ntop"

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-cache search ntop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt install ntopng
```

This should install ntop and all required packages. To run ntopng open the terminal and type `ntopng`